# Lower oven smells + high flames, rest of range OK (KitchenAid - Natural Gas)

Tags: repair, kitchens, gas, oven, natural-gas

My SO and I are stumped with our KitchenAid's lower oven (Double Oven, model KFGD500ESS01, Natural Gas) and are hoping for second thoughts before we throw in the towel and bring in a professional.

tl;dr: Lower oven emitting strong smells (not rotten eggs); flames are also excessively high (blue, occasional yellow tip). New OEM igniter, adjustments to air shutter, and burner tube had no effect. Stovetop and upper oven works as normal.

[See pictures of burner tube here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/9fAHNXp4s5d6Z1Bc9).

More detail on what we've done follows. SO has been able to repair every appliance in our home, but KitchenAid has been testing our patience -- and welcome any ideas on fixing the smell and flame issue.

---

Both ovens stopped heating a few months ago and found upper and lower oven igniters were faulty (broiler igniter OK), so we replaced them (OEM parts used throughout).

3 weeks later, the lower oven started smelling shortly after turning it on. We ruled out a gas leak since the smell went away when turned off, and the top oven and stovetop were fine.

We replaced the lower igniter again in case the new one was a dud -- didn't work.

Turned it on again and noticed moisture on the stove griddle top, high flames from the oven burner tube, and a lot of soot on the tube and heat shield (pictures linked above).

This seemed like incomplete combustion, but we adjusted the air shutter ***and*** swapped the burner tube, but still no effect to the smell or flame.

The oven was here when we moved in and for a NG hookup; we have not made other adjustments to the oven outside the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This stinkiness only happens with the lower oven?  Have you tried swapping the upper and lower oven burners (assuming they're the same)?

Comment: @Huesmann Yep - after replacing the igniter and adjusting the air filter didn't produce results, we swapped the burner tubes (upper oven burner tube doesn't have soot). It still flared and smelled.